# prove $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a(a+b)}\ge\frac{4}{ac+bd}$

Tags: inequality, fractions, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c,d$ be positives. Show that
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{a(a+b)}\ge\dfrac{4}{ac+bd}$$

Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{a(a+b)} \cdot\sum_{cyc}a(a+b)\ge (1+1+1+1)^2$$
it suffient
$$\dfrac{16}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+ab)}\ge\dfrac{4}{ac+bd}$$
However this is wrong inequality

Answer (score 3):

By AM-GM $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{abcd}}\geq\frac{4}{ac+bd}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^2+ab}\geq\frac{2}{\sqrt{abcd}}.$$
Since the last inequality is homogeneous, we can assume that  $abcd=1$.

Now, let $a=\frac{y}{x}$, $b=\frac{z}{y}$ and $c=\frac{t}{z}$, where $x$, $y$, $z$ and $t$ are positives.

Hence, $d=\frac{x}{t}$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\frac{y}{x}\left(\frac{y}{x}+\frac{z}{y}\right)}\geq2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{y^2+xz}\geq2.$$
But by C-S we have 
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{y^2+xz}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^4}{x^2y^2+x^3z}\geq\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2y^2+x^3z)}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2)^2\geq2\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2y^2+x^3z)$$ or
$$(x^2+z^2)(x-z)^2+(y^2+t^2)(y-t)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

$$\Leftrightarrow \left ( \dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{d}\right )^2\cdot \dfrac{1}{4+\dfrac{b}{a}+\dfrac{c}{b}+\dfrac{d}{c}+\dfrac{a}{d}}\ge \dfrac{4}{ac+bd}$$

$$\left ( \left (\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b} \right )+\left (\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{d}\right )\right )^2 \cdot (ac)\ge 4 \left( \dfrac{c}{b}+\dfrac{d}{a}\right)+\dfrac{2(a+b)(c+d)}{bd}$$

$$\left ( \left (\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{d} \right )+\left (\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{b}\right )\right )^2 \cdot (bd)\ge 4 \left( \dfrac{b}{a}+\dfrac{d}{c}\right)+\dfrac{2(d+a)(b+c)}{ac}$$

So:

$$  \left (\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b} +\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{d}\right )^2\cdot(ac+bd)\ge 4\left(\dfrac{b}{a}+\dfrac{c}{b}+\dfrac{d}{c}+\dfrac{a}{d}\right)+16$$